# Kohana DB - using SQL_CACHE

Tags: mysql, caching, kohana

Is there a way to implement this with Kohana's (3.x) database query builder:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE id, name FROM customer;
```

I know I can use the method *cached* for cache mysql results, but I want mysql to cache the results, not Kohana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think kohana have SQL_CACHE defined anywhere. But if you feel show is stopping just due to not having sql_cache in kohana there is one thing i can suggest you. Make your own sql_cache method which is very easy.

In modules/database/classes/kohana/database/query/builder/select.php define $_sqlcache variable. Just like "protected $_distinct = FALSE;"

```
protected $_sqlcache = FALSE;
```

add a method

```
public function sqlcache($value)
{
    $this->_sqlcache = (bool) $value;    
    return $this;
}
```

in compile() method

```
//Just below these lines
/*if ($this->_distinct === TRUE)
{
    // Select only unique results
    $query .= 'DISTINCT ';
}*/

if ($this->_sqlcache === TRUE)
{
    $query .= 'SQL_CACHE ';
}

//$query = DB::select('id', 'name')->sqlcache(TRUE)->from('customer');
```

I did this in Kohana 3.2 and it certainly does produces a query like you asked for but i'm not sure if it is proper way. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, probably this is the way to go. I will extend the class to not owerwrite the original source and implement it myself.
Thank you for suggestion.